# Moodle Webservice API dont returns correctly

Tags: web-services, rest, moodle

I am currently trying two methods of web service API (Moodle 2.6) to call with REST:

## 1 core_course_get_categories

## 2 core_course_create_courses

With both I have the following problems:

## 1

The function returns me categories back but unfortunately no subcategories. Even if I add like the documentation says the parameter "addsubcategories = 1", only the top-level Categories are sent back. An idea what the issue could be?

## 2

The course creation works so far, but I would like to assign the instructor to a specific user. Now when I create a course, it is indeed created under the users with the WS-rights. Is there a possibility to change the instructor?

Short background:

We have a central system where teachers can save new course information. Here should you have the opportunity to create a Moodle course immediately. We have in both systems a unique identifier of the user that should become the instructor. Of course, must be prior to the course, the Category / Subcategory be selected.

I would be happy about feedback!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer however I think it might be a valid solution to the first issue above and hopefully will help someone with similar issues.

A webservice user with the permission ***moodle/category:manage*** will be able to see all categories, hidden or visible as well as all levels of categories.

However there is no mention of this restriction in the Moodle API docs (that I could find at least).

Hope that helps anyone with this issue in the future.

Regards